# useState variable does not get changed after updated in useEffect by event

Tags: reactjs, typescript, babylonjs

i am trying to update a stateful variable `cameraPosition` using Typescript, React and Babylonjs.

this is the code snipped:

```
  const camera = scene?.cameras[0];
  const prevPositionRef = useRef<Nullable<Vector3>>(null);
  
  
  const [cameraPosition, setCameraPosition] = useState<Vector3>(
    new Vector3(0, 0, 0)
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    if (camera) {
      const onAfterInput = () => {
        if (
          !prevPositionRef.current ||
          !prevPositionRef.current.equals(camera.position)
        ) {
          console.log("change") //also logs every changed frame!

          setCameraPosition(camera.position); // does not set the position (or does it?!)

          prevPositionRef.current = camera.position.clone();
        }
      };

      camera.onAfterCheckInputsObservable.add(() => {
        // it correctly triggers every frame
        onAfterInput();
      });

      return () => {
        camera.onAfterCheckInputsObservable.removeCallback(() => {
          onAfterInput();
        });
      };
    }
  }, [camera]);

 console.log(cameraPosition) // does not log position!?
```

i even tried to listen to changes of cameraPosition by doing this:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("cameraPosition updated:", cameraPosition);
  }, [cameraPosition]);
```

but no success.

there are 2 console.log() positions:
the first one does log on every frame when the camera was changed correctly.
the second one does not log the cameraPosition. and i just cannot figure out why.
it seems the algorithm does not even realize that the cameraPosition changed.

What am i doing wrong here? i want to use cameraPosition in other components too.

any help would be great!

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The value of `cameraPosition` is already `camera.position`, so when you try and set the new state it compares `camera.position` with `camera.position` and correctly decides no update is needed, so no rerender is triggered.

If you want to rerender when the camera position changes, you can change:

```js
setCameraPosition(camera.position)
```

to

```js
setCameraPosition(camera.position.clone())
```

However, you don't want to rerender your components every frame, since that is bad for performance. You should try and find an alternate solution to your problem - perhaps run your logic in `onAfterInput` instead of going through React?

Comment: yes - the performance is just straight out terrible.  I could try to get the logic in `onAfterInput` but if i need the value in other components, how would i do that?

Comment: can you not just use `scene?.cameras[0]?.position` in each of the components? Or if you specifically need it after an input update, move this logic to a custom hook